# How can I use an animated bezier curve as a boolean for a mesh?

Tags: animation, modifiers, bezier-curves, baking

I have a bezier curve that I have animated with an armature and hooks.

It is *2D*, has a *fill mode* set to both, and is *extruded*.

[image]

Now, I want to use that curve to make a diff operation with a mesh.  Is that possible and how ?

Eventually, I might need to convert the curve to a mesh but how to do this since it is animated ?  Thanks !

Thanks !

Comment: Export as Alembic, import back and add Boolean modifier ...?

Comment: Holy shit, it works !!! Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Great it works for you ... just a note - this format is a sequence of vertex positions (can be exported fluid sim or what ever) ... vertex on one frame is not the same on another frame ... it means this format can't handle UVmaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Export as Alembic, import back and add Boolean modifier ...*

[image]

---

Here example ... curve Full, Depth, Extrude ... animated with two Shape Keys
[image]

**Export as Alembic** ... under export Options check **Curve to Mesh**.
**Import Alembic back** ... it comes as object with modifier **Mesh Sequence Cache**.
[image]

Now you can add some object for boolean operation (here Cube) ... select your imported .abc object and add **Boolean modifier**.

[image]

[image]